# Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{u'slug': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'blog/(?P<pk>\\d+)/comment/$']

Tags: python, django

I am getting an error - Reverse for 'add_comment' with keyword arguments '{u'slug': None}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'blog/(?P\d+)/comment/$']

I added - app_name= 'blog' - to urls to solve the earlier error of namespace

but now I am stuck with a new error

my urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/comment/$', views.add_comment, name='add_comment')
```

my views.py

```
def add_comment(request, slug):
post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = post
        comment.save()
        return redirect('blog:post', slug=post.slug)
else:
    form = CommentForm()

template = 'blog/add_comment.html'
context = {'form': form}
return render(request, template, context)
```

my models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
body = models.TextField()
date = models.DateTimeField()
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_absoulte_url(self):
       return reverse('blog:post.html', args=[self.slug])

class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', blank=True, 
null=True)
user = models.CharField(max_length=250)
email = models.EmailField()
body = models.TextField()
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def approved(self):
    self.approved = True
    self.save()

def __str__(self):
    return self.user
```

my template add_comment.html

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Add new comment</h1>
<form method='POST'>{% csrf_token %}
{{ from.as_p }}
<button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This isn't coming from this code. It's coming from a page which is trying to link to the add_comment page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is coming from a page where you had given the link to `add comment`, most probably in the detailed **blog/post** page.

You are creating the `add comment` URL without passing the `pk` argument to it.

It should be something like.

```
<a href="{% url 'add_comment' blog.pk %}">Add Comment</a>
```

But you have missed `blog.pk` or something like `post.pk` in creating URL.
Just do that and error will be resolved.

Comment: @user9405106, feel glad that it helped.

Comment: But I got another error after that which said that I needed to add argument 'pk' to the add_comment function which meant i had to increase an argument to the return redirect() as well. Do I need to pass an extra argument in add_comment() and return redirect()

Comment: why you are using `slug` just replace with pk and find the `Post` using pk itself.

Comment: I thought using slug in the urls would have made it a bit easier? But it was not working

Comment: So you can use `pk` now and that would be better.